# Change border width on one element without moving siblings

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something with css buttons, but when the user presses a button, the sibling buttons move just a bit.

I can't use outline because of the border-radius.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

An example:

```css
.main-body {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 0 2vw 2vw 0;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 4%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  transition: width 0.1s, height 0.1s, border 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.button:active {
  border-width: 0;
  width: calc(40% - 2vw);
  height: calc(40% - 2vw);
  margin-top: calc(4% + 2vw);
  margin-left: calc(4% + 2vw);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-body">
    <button class="button">1</button>
    <button class="button">2</button>
    <button class="button">3</button>
    <button class="button">4</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `vertical-align: bottom;` to `.button`

```css
.main-body {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  vertical-align: bottom; /* now bottoms will align so no buttons will move */
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 0 2vw 2vw 0;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 4%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  transition: width 0.1s, height 0.1s, border 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.button:active {
  border-width: 0;
  width: calc(40% - 2vw);
  height: calc(40% - 2vw);
  margin-top: calc(4% + 2vw);
  margin-left: calc(4% + 2vw);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-body">
    <button class="button">1</button>
    <button class="button">2</button>
    <button class="button">3</button>
    <button class="button">4</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code, Change

```
 .button:active { 
    margin-top: calc(4% + 2vw);
  }
```

to

```
  .button:active { 
     top: calc(4% + 2vw);
  }
```

```css
.main-body {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 0 2vw 2vw 0;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 4%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  transition: width 0.1s, height 0.1s, border 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
}

.button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.button:active {
  border-width: 0;
  width: calc(40% - 2vw);
  height: calc(40% - 2vw);
  top: calc(4% + 2vw);
  margin-left: calc(4% + 2vw);
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-body">
    <button class="button">1</button>
    <button class="button">2</button>
    <button class="button">3</button>
    <button class="button">4</button>
  </div>
</body>
```